Ament Cmake doesnt extend LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Im using a precompiled version of pytorch in my Ros2 Humble Project.
Initially add the library folder to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH via export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:/root/pytorch/libtorch and this works fine as find_package(Torch) works. Compling/Linking is OK
But when I inspect the binary with ld <my binary> it cant resolve the pytorch .so file paths; They are not set.
My CMake look like this at the moment and I would like to get rid of setting the RPATH manually. Does anybody know what the problem is?
...
find_package(Torch REQUIRED CONFIG)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")
#Ament cmake somehow doesnt set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/root/pytorch/libtorch/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)




add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        src/to_ros.cpp
        src/to_realm.cpp
)


target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
 "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
 "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>"
 ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#include/link ros dependencies with this macro

ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} rclcpp cv_bridge message_filters sensor_msgs std_msgs realm_interfaces geometry_msgs tf2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} realm_stages)


ament_export_targets(${PROJECT_NAME}Targets HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
ament_export_dependencies(Torch)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

# Install directories files.
install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)


# This should be the last line
ament_package()

